# Is there a way in TypeScript to get typing from a generic that extend a fixed interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The problem is:

I've a class that have some methods that make specific api calls. This class get, as constructor parameter, an interface  where there are a sets of methods used to transform the API responses in something else. But from the API class prospective, is not necessary to know the trasformer implementation, in this way is possible to implement the transformer in any way. What I would like to do is to know the returned type once everything has been instantiated.

**Code example of the wanted behaviour**

```js
type SomeObj = {
  stringKey: string;
  numberKey: number;
}

type SomeOtherObj = {
  stringKey: string;
  numberKey: number;
}

function fetch1() {
  return { stringKey: 'stringKey', numberKey: 2 }
}

function fetch2() {
  return { stringKey: 'stringKey', numberKey: 2 }
}

interface IATransformer {
  transformResOne: (res1: SomeObj) => any;
  transformResTwo: (res2: SomeOtherObj) => any;
}

class ATransformer {
  transformResOne(res1: SomeObj): string {
    return res1.stringKey
  }
  transformResTwo(res2: SomeOtherObj): number {
    return res2.numberKey;
  }
}

interface IA<T extends ATransformer> {
  getOne: (param: string) => any; // Not "any" but something from the generic
  getTwo: (param2: string) => any; // Not "any" but something from the generic
}

class A<T extends ATransformer> implements IA<T> {
  constructor(
    private readonly transformer: T
  ) { }

  // Return type doesn't work in this way but don't know how to sobstitute it
  getOne(param: string): ReturnType<this.transformer.getOne> {
    const res = fetch1()
    return this.transformer.transformResOne(res)
  }

  // Return type doesn't work in this way but don't know how to sobstitute it
  getTwo(param2: string): ReturnType<this.transformer.getTwo> {
    const res = fetch2();
    return this.transformer.transformResTwo(res)
  }
}

const transformer = new ATransformer();
// Generic is inferred from the parameter
const a = new A(transformer);

// Desired result ---> ERROR: the type returned from the function is not number but string
const resOneResult: number = a.getOne('Some string')
```

I already tried by using generics and my best guess was something like this:

```js
class A implements IA {
  constructor(
    private readonly transformer: IATransformer
  ) { }

  getOne(param: string): ReturnType<typeof this.transformer.transformResOne> {
    const res = fetch1()
    return this.transformer.transformResOne(res)
  }

  getTwo(param2: string): ReturnType<typeof this.transformer.transformResTwo> {
    const res = fetch2();
    return this.transformer.transformResTwo(res)
  }
}
```

But of course it doesn't work!

Comment: This doesn't use generics at all - you did not declare any generic type parameters.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/mplr6m), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (For example, the only errors present should be the ones you are running into; there should be no undeclared types or values.) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz this is the point, I don't know how exactly write the thing that I would like to do and the upper representation is the best that I can do.

Comment: @kaya3 Updated code by using generics, the point here is that I don't understand hot to correctly use them to get the desired result. I updated the code by using the way I tried, but, i know, the compile will complain everywhere

Comment: Sure, but I'm asking that your example code doesn't use things like `SomeObj` and `fetch(...)` since neither of those are valid as-is, and those aren't where your problem is.  If I have to make up my own types and fill in the `...` or replace `fetch()` with some other testable function, then that's time I'm spending getting to the part where the problem is observable, which could be better spent actually trying to solve the problem.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @jcalz Sure! Did it, hopefully is better now

Comment: So, you could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXRMkm), but I'd be inclined to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOayzm) instead, since the compiler infers more accurate types that way.  If either of those meet your needs I'd be happy to write up an answer; otherwise, please elaborate about what is not working for you.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I'm going to use the first solution that you propose. Already tested the second one but there are some classes that have up to 8 transformers and I don't like to have 8 different generic types! Let me know what you think about, anyway write the answer, I'm going to select it as the best answer of course 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a generic type `T` that extends `IATransformer`, the return type of the `transformResOne()` method of type `T` can be written as `ReturnType<T['transformResOne']>`, using [the `ReturnType` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to get the return type, and the `T[K]` [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type of the member of `T` at key `"transformResOne"`.  And an analogous statement can be made for `transformResTwo`.  That means we can defined `IA` and `A` like this:

```
interface IA<T extends IATransformer> {
  getOne: (param: string) => ReturnType<T['transformResOne']>;
  getTwo: (param2: string) => ReturnType<T['transformResTwo']>;
}

class A<T extends IATransformer> implements IA<T> {
  constructor(
    private readonly transformer: T
  ) { }

  getOne(param: string): ReturnType<T['transformResOne']> {
    const res = fetch1()
    return this.transformer.transformResOne(res)
  }

  getTwo(param2: string): ReturnType<T['transformResTwo']> {
    const res = fetch2();
    return this.transformer.transformResTwo(res)
  }
}
```

This should work as you want:

```
const transformer = new ATransformer();
const a = new A(transformer);
const resOneResult: number = a.getOne('Some string'); // error!
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

---

However, note that inside the implementation of `A`, the compiler can't really follow such higher-order type juggling involving a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `ReturnType` that depends on an unresolved [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter like `T`.

Instead it takes some shortcuts, like inferring that `this.transformer.transformResOne(res)` returns the same thing that `IATransformer`'s `transformResOne(res)` method does, namely [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  The `any` type is intentionally loose, and so the compiler will not notice or warn you if you use it incorrectly:

```
getOops(param2: string): ReturnType<T['transformResTwo']> {
  const res = fetch2();
  return this.transformer.transformResOne(res); // no error, inferred as any
}
```

So you have to be careful with such an implementation.

---

If you want to ensure more type safety, I'd recommend avoiding such conditional types, if possible.  One way to do this which still allows good type inference is to refactor to make everything generic in those return types `T1` and `T2`:

```
interface IA<T1, T2> {
  getOne: (param: string) => T1;
  getTwo: (param2: string) => T2;
}

interface IATransformer<T1, T2> {
  transformResOne: (res1: SomeObj) => T1;
  transformResTwo: (res2: SomeOtherObj) => T2;
}

class A<T1, T2> implements IA<T1, T2> {
  constructor(
    private readonly transformer: IATransformer<T1, T2>
  ) { }

  getOne(param: string) {
    const res = fetch1()
    return this.transformer.transformResOne(res)
  }

  getTwo(param2: string) {
    const res = fetch2();
    return this.transformer.transformResTwo(res)
  }

  getOops(param2: string): T2 {
    const res = fetch2();
    return this.transformer.transformResOne(res); // error!
  }
}
```

As you mentioned, you might not want to do this for something with a large number of type parameters, but you can see that the compiler is much better about catching errors and inferring types (you don't even have to annotate the return types of `getOne()` and `getTwo()`).   Let's just be sure that it still works though:

```
const transformer = new ATransformer();
const a = new A(transformer);
const resOneResult: number = a.getOne('Some string'); // error!
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZQPYFsYHkBGArOBeOAb1DjgGcwAnASwDsBzAaRggC5yq76BuEuWgK4pMMSszb8hIyrxABfUKEixEqDGAAWorLgLEQpCjQbj2RrrNKDho05JszQCkKABmA2gGMw1JLTiuMGCeGgCMABQAlER8lEEClP6EHMZMLOwA5OYmLBkANPbSdgBMcM7Obh7evv6BwRrFUTEGcHFgCUkpXHZZnDkQ+YW26XCl5YogdGCirgCGnvAAkgCCACqUs7RkrkiUaJTNpFSb27soAEowZOi0MOzhcWSh7MhoOtF4AHxwmxCWcMctjs9pcyKsAO5Ie6PYovNToTTaHAfb6-WQVECeAA2szIZDgaw2QLOokOAKJpxBVxuMAeV2eqjeyLMfXoZNIbQ6rXpADpsmkIHxnEcKcCLlcIUg6WRYYz1FpKO92NZpOzue1EtyZTyVcM-kKnBMpjN5ktlgAeVZwGAAD2mtAAJviVusTmLRN99KR6EEafcoLMNigWakUXBLhraKtoDBLQBtDKAyni663DIAXU+-x9YEl-sDsxQsv5YYjHWjsHjidFZ1BkozWcNLkxOLxBMt1rtMEdzsJbpJlG+1BQUCxMDQtDAvctnr4nj8RgE3l24T4pCgNAAbrNptzZg6-FiIOT+3tROxVnxoskMd7fbdwgGgyGuJF2GXEhXY6sE0mxaCaQbNV5y2MAtXwAIghCCJIjXdUuU0agyB5P8BxQmsqVTWlHlglpbzgHNJUfAsixfBg33DeJPxjKtUMw+tM2AhcwMeCC6hCRpIn+DkqP8RDkLo-Z0NPFMiJwg1mzvMB0CQKAyGIoNi1ZCiPyjGif2rES60hICvVIOAQIocCCHYhoom4+DNX44TiTPSgbOTACHxw7g4AAejc-gkGtShKF2Ao6ECXyYAdH58V+CSMUMsDBNJAhbnBAlXVs-ZzNAaKfgghKCXCWLKC49LmK1GlQQELEwGVKQ4p+HkcxpcIMleeB+QyLj3M80Q-MoABCUAPLgL84F6VIMjgJCvLA3EyGoehaFmTAxwBbzlHgDJdUoDIJgmOa0DIAMFkouZlwOfQ+BWuUdAgvTDFZOx+Qs9a7HW-58POpqEQVS69Dg-k7tZB6qrEEZnokvh3C8Hw-Eg+oYLVTlNWSX6RmG7pcgKR6RjGUGWnB6oodMzi4d4ogun6TIkYGdHAZKMpsdIbEpqSjD9jVQSnOw+k4SZbAKP5NUeMjLVQj5W6WDg4V9LZiVIWlWV3sRRVmSGE64IFrkYR1amWAsiX8ONSgjrNS1QgKVZilnFopL9OAFMLMj6DDVZQgswjIXzRT7cd4oXomUh9cNuAXWZ0RjdN83WeZ9noU5i7kXwb4nYsqWwTdm2YS5+UkR5+OBu9umDNbfELSdsOhxHMcJynQPi5N3OLf0gzmMoJcwBXVW4A3aht13OJ90PY88vYIORJDku67g69ack-S6ofJ87dJh3+cb0DjOh6Conb+G+I0JCHPdezk-q8TLanuDXalefSMX6924y1iTKgsyCtPtWrN3gTg8PyPpalE+G-wlbWS8kr5KVDBeUo119L3yuGxJ+nELJvx3nvPK+9azUmclcNq-VOq7F6qfXWvsV5GTyllGAiU+wpVEGlFoGVZhkIoblL+L96ZFUeCVK4ZUKrKwgrMWq95aSNTUIvVqrkcG+TwXwfqg0UYMFGuNWgSBJp4hmnNBa8BW4AhjENdam1mxOCAA)

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Thank you!